# add to favorite button not styled correctly in exponent and shoutem

Tags: react-native, exponentjs

In this following example, my add-to-favorites button is not right aligned and is black instead of white.  I don't see any styles defined anywhere and I can't seem to get to the safari inspector using exponent.

Incorrect

[image: incorrect black star]

Correct white star that's right aligned

[image]

Looking at the sample code 
https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/examples/components/Tiles.js
- it looks like it should style it to white and right aligned but it doesn't do so in my case.  Do I need to wrap it in an enclosing style?  How do i debug this?

```
render() {

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      styleName="large-banner"
      source={{ uri: 'https://shoutem.github.io/img/ui-toolkit/examples/image-3.png' }}
    >
      <Tile>
        <View styleName="actions">
          <Button styleName="tight clear"><Icon name="add-to-favorites" /></Button>
        </View>
        <Title>HOW TO MAINTAIN YOUR MENTAL HEALTH IN 2016</Title>
        <Caption>6557 Americo Hills Apt. 118</Caption>
      </Tile>
    </Image>
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was importing `View` from react-native.  Once I started to import `View` from `@shoutem/ui` it carried over the correct styles.